# Veeam SureBackup VB Script Fails When Querying VM Services

Tags: vbscript, veeam

We are running Windows servers in a Hyper-V environment. I created a VB script to check that certain services started properly during a SureBackup job. It runs fine if I run it from a VM in the virtual lab against a machine also in the virtual lab. It also runs fine if I run it from a production VM against a machine also in the production environment. What doesn't work is trying to run it on a machine in the production environment (IE: the Veeam Backup and Replication Server) and one of the VMs under test running in the virtual lab during a SureBackup job. In that case, I get a

> Windows error 800706BA - The RPC server cannot be reached.

The relevant portion of my script is as follows:

```
Dim objSWbemServices 
Dim objSWbemLocator

Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
On Error Resume Next
Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(sServer, "Root\CIMv2", gsUser, gsPassword)
```

The 'ConnectServer' call is the one producing the error.

NOTE: sServer is set to the proxy IP of the target server, `gsUser` is set to the domain administrator and `gsPassword` is set appropriately for the admin account.

Our Veeam VBR Server is not domain joined per suggested best practice. The script fails the same when run from that server or any other in the production environment. The only real difference being that since I long onto the other servers as domain administrator, I don't have to explicitly set the user/password in the connection call and they are left null.

I'm not well versed in VBS. All of the research I have done didn't point to anything useful. I'm hopeful that someone here might have a suggestion.

Comment: Check your network, if they can't see each other this will never work.